# Best Way Of Doing MySQL Exists / In / Join

Tags: mysql

I'm not sure the best way to do this.  I am trying to get all contacts with a particular subscription, but also if they user has a subscription to something else.

Here's the query for getting users with a particular subscription:

```
SELECT a.* FROM portal_contacts a
                    INNER JOIN portal_subscriptions_rel b
                        ON a.id=b.contactid
                     INNER JOIN portal_users c
                        ON c.id=a.user_id 
                     WHERE (b.subscription_id='1' OR b.subscription_id='3')
```

But I want to add on something like:

```
AND (c.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM portal_subscriptions_rel WHERE subscription_id='5') OR c.user_id IN (SELECT user_id FROM portal_subscriptions_rel WHERE subscription_id='6'))
```

Just wondering what the fastest way of doing this would be.

---

**Edit 1**
Ok so I changed the IN query to:

```
AND (EXISTS (SELECT id FROM portal_subscriptions_rel WHERE user_id=c.id AND subscription_id='5') OR EXISTS (SELECT id FROM portal_subscriptions_rel WHERE user_id=c.id AND subscription_id='6'))
```

Anything faster?

Comment: this itself should be faster. Why do you think the query is inefficient? run a explain plan and see the query plan.

Comment: @Rahul I'm just worried if the query is ran  and has 100 subscriptions with a bunch of sub queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just add the extra condition as an inner join:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM portal_contacts a INNER JOIN
     portal_subscriptions_rel b
     ON a.id=b.contactid INNER JOIN
     portal_users c
     ON c.id=a.user_id INNER JOIN
     portal_subscriptions_rel psr2
     on c.user_id = psr2.user_id and
        psr2.subscription_id = '5'
WHERE (b.subscription_id='1' OR b.subscription_id='3') ;
```

The `join` is generally the safest way to add the condition.  `Exists` also works fine.  And, it would be preferable if more than one row from `portal_subscriptions_rel` could match the condition.  `IN` is logically equivalent to the `exists`.  However, until the most recent versions of MySQL, the optimizer produced a very poor plan for these queries.

Comment: Since I already inner join'd that table, I should do it again?

Comment: @Gordon, this would be the best way of doing; I was planning to suggest the same but wasn't sure whether OP has a relation between tables `portal_subscriptions_rel` and `portal_users`

Comment: @Michael . . . Yes.  The condition is different from the `join` condition (if I understand the filtering correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this then:

```
SELECT a.* FROM portal_contacts a
                    INNER JOIN portal_subscriptions_rel b
                        ON a.id=b.contactid
                     INNER JOIN portal_users c
                        ON c.id=a.user_id 
                     WHERE (b.subscription_id='1' OR b.subscription_id='3') 
                     AND c.user_id IN 
(SELECT user_id FROM portal_subscriptions_rel
WHERE subscription_id in(5,6,......,n-1,n))
```